# The function does not redirect the user to the next question

Tags: python

I have already tried many times to fix this problem, but I can not solve it in any way. I use an index as a variable to move the user to the next question, but after correct and incorrect answers, the index remains at 0.

```
score = 0
index = 0
num = 0
user_answer = ""
correct = ""

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

question_list = ["What is this shape? \na. Square \nb. Triangle \nc. Oval \nAnswer: ", "What color is this shape? \na. Blue \nb. Red \nc. Orange \nAnswer: "]
answer_list = ["a", "c"]

def AnswerCheck (num):
  global user_answer, correct, index, score
  while (correct == "false"):
    user_answer = input(question_list[num])
    if (user_answer == answer_list[num]):
      score += 1
      print("Correct!")
      print("Score:", score)
      print("\n")
    else:
      print("Incorrect!")
      print("Score:", score)
      print("\n")
    index = index + 1

while index < len(question_list):
    correct = "false"
    AnswerCheck(index)
```

Comment: Where do you define your `index`, `user_answer`, and `score`  variables?

Comment: I added to my code

Comment: If you start out with `(correct == "false")`, and you want `while (correct == "false"):` to stop, then something has to happen *inside the loop* to make that no longer true. (Or you can `break` or `return`, of course.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason why the index isn't moving is that you are not letting it execute. first things first, you need to define the variables outside of the functions then make a function called main. main will be the driver function that you will be using to execute the rest of the code. the next step is to place the `index += 1` outside of the while loop, then and a `return` call at the end of the function to push the results back to main. finally, you need to stop the while loop that is asking the question, to do this add `break`. this will stop the while loop from executing if the correct answer is entered.

```
question_list = ["What is this shape? \na. Square \nb. Triangle \nc. Oval \nAnswer: ", "What color is this shape? \na. Blue \nb. Red \nc. Orange \nAnswer: "]
answer_list = ["a", "c"]
user_answer = ""
correct = "false"
index = 0
score = 0

def AnswerCheck (num):
    global index, score, user_answer, correct
    while (correct == "false"):
        user_answer = input(question_list[num])
        if (user_answer == answer_list[num]):
            score += 1
            print("Correct!")
            print("Score:", score)
            print("\n")
            break
        else:
            print("Incorrect!")
            print("Score:", score)
            print("\n")
    index = index + 1
    return
    
def main():
    while index < len(question_list):
        correct = "false"
        AnswerCheck(index)
main()
```

This code ran fine on my side let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

You have this condition `while (correct == "false")`, `correct` variable has the value `"false"` from the start, and you don't change `correct` value anywhere in the body of your loop. Hence you will never exit the loop.

And about `index` remaining always zero. It's not true. You can `print` the value of `index` before `user_answer = input(question_list[num])` and you will see that it has changed.

The problem is that you are passing the `index` as an argument here `AnswerCheck(index)`. Because `int` is a primitive type in Python the value of the `index` variable will be copied and stored in the `num` variable inside your `AnswerCheck` function.

Because of that, `num` in `AnswerCheck` and `index` from the outside scope are not connected in any way. That means changing `index` will not change the value of `num` and vice versa.

And you will never exit `AnswerCheck` as I mentioned in the beginning, so your `num` variable will never change, and you stuck with the `num` being 0.

There are a lot of ways to solve it. The most simple ones are changing your `while` condition or updating the `num` variable, depending on the desired results.

Also, consider avoiding using `global` it's not the best practice and can lead to some difficulties debugging. [You can read more reasoning about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad).